# Value of a props is not same as sent in the callback funtion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a react component as :

```js
const CustomDatePicker = ({ errors, id, name, control, rules, getValues, minDate, maxDate, placeholder, required, defaultValue, ...rest }) => {
     console.log("required 1", name, required);
    const inputRef = React.useRef();
    const validateField = () => {
        console.log("required 2", required, name)
        if (required && !getValues(name)) {
            return false
        }
        else if (getValues(name)) {
            let dateObj = typeof (getValues(name)) == 'string' ? new Date(getValues(name)) : getValues(name)
            return !isNaN(dateObj);
        }
        else return true;
    }

    return (
        <div className="form-group custom-input-container">
            <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                <Controller
                    name={name}
                    margin="normal"
                    fullWidth
                    variant="outlined"
                    onFocus={() => {
                        if (inputRef.current) {
                            inputRef.current.focus()
                        }
                    }}
                    defaultValue={defaultValue}
                    as={<KeyboardDatePicker
                        inputRef={inputRef}
                        className="custom-date-col"
                        fullWidth
                        autoOk
                        clearable
                        variant="inline"
                        inputVariant="outlined"
                        placeholder={placeholder}
                        minDate={minDate}
                        format="dd-MM-yyyy"
                        maxDate={maxDate}
                    />}
                    rules={{
                        validate: validateField
                    }}
                    control={control}
                    errors={errors}
                    {...rest}
                />
            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
        </div>
    );
};
export default CustomDatePicker;
```

and a parent component uses the above as follows :

```js
export default function Dummy(props) {
  const [req,setReq]=useState(false);
  return (    
    <div className="FamilyDetails__emergency-form-row FamilyDetails__three-col-grid">
      <CustomDatePicker
        name={`marriageDate`}
        errors={props.errors}
        control={props.control}
        maxDate={new Date()}
        minDate={getMinDate()}
        placeholder={"dateOfMarriageLbl"}
        required={req}
        defaultValue={new Date()}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I use the above components in the form. Initially "required" prop is going to be false then later it will be changed to true. When I submit the form `validateField` method gets called and the `required` prop value in console is printed as false whereas the original value is true. Then console printed outside the function prints "require" prop value as true. The value of "required" prop in `validateField` function is taking the initial value with which component is initially rendered. Please help me through this.

Comment: you probably should provide detail on the version and perhaps a codesandbox as well.

Comment: @Bill please find codesandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-date-picker-emeuy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like react-hook-forms caches validation and the issue has been resolved in latest versions. find the discussion [here](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/1749). This has solved my issue.